# Win form slow to draw controls when shifting tabpages

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, performance, serialization

I use winform C#, where I am trying to serializing data to XML when a tabpage has been choosen.
When I shift to a tabpage like tabPageShowHobby, all the controls (textbox etc) on the winforms has not yet been drawn (slow drawing)

I guess it is the serializing of data to XML that slows Down of Drawing the controls on the form. How can this problem be solved ?

```
 private void tabControlMyHobbies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (tabControlShowMyHobbies.SelectedTab == tabPageShowHobby)
        writeDataToXml();
    else
    if (tabControlShowMyFood.SelectedTab == tabPageFood)
    {
        do something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this on a background thread.

Comment: Just paper over the problem, insert tabControlRFMeasurement.Update() so the delay isn't so obvious.  You only have to do the drastic thing when it takes multiple seconds.  It never does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) to write your data to XML. For example:

```
if (tabControlShowMyHobbies.SelectedTab == tabPageShowHobby)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { writeDataToXml(); });
}
else
```

If you're using an earlier version of C# that doesn't support tasks, you can call [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => { writeDataToXml(); });
```

Either of those will execute the `writeDataToXml` method on a background thread, leaving your UI thread free.